# Invalid foreground color specified: "default". Expected one of (black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white)

Tags: symfony

I upgrade my symfony from 2.3 to 2.8 recently.

I'm trying to deploy my app with capifony to test server but the console is throwing this error:

> Invalid foreground color specified: "default". Expected one of (black,
>   red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white)

I think it's related about Console component but i can't find why it doesn't work.

In local envoirment it works perfectly at dev and prod envs.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I found the mistake, version of dependencies are wrong, i have sensio/distribution-bundle in version ~2.0 and it requires version 3. It solved my problem. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

To solve it just update the following packages:

```
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "^4.0"
"symfony/console": "^3.0"
```